# Open modal dynamically via livewire

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

i'm developing an application via laravel 8 and livewire, in my view `gestionale.blade.php` i've a livewire component with button.
When I click a button, for example `Aggiungi Assegnatario`, I call the following click event `wire: click =" checkId "`.
in the component I have the checkId that verifies if a variable is set or not, and if it is not set, then checkId performs a `redirect back()->with('error', 'my message')` and which is correctly displayed, following whose modal does not need to be shown.
The problem is that clicking on the button the modal is always shown ... do you have any suggestions on how to solve this?

here my code:

- gestionale-modal-component.blade.php

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-12">
        @if (!empty(session()->get('error')))
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show solid alert-rounded">
                    <button type="button" class="close h-100" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span><i
                                class="mdi mdi-close"></i></span>
                    </button>
                    <strong>Error!</strong>{{ session()->get('error') }}
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <!-- button per l'apertura dei modal -->
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PagamentoLongModal">Aggiungi pagamento</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" data-toggle="modal" wire:click="checkId" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">Aggiungi assegnatario</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ShowPagamentiModal">Pagamenti</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ProcedureInesigibilitaModal">Procedure/Inesigibilit&agrave;</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- gestionale.blade.php

```
{{-- Extends layout --}}
@extends('layout.layout2')



{{-- Content --}}
@section('content')

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row page-titles mx-0">
        <div class="col-sm-6 p-md-0">
            <div class="welcome-text">
                <h4>Benvenuto sul Gestionale</h4>
                <span>Qui sono listate pratche, partite e articoli</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- import del componente gestionale header filter per i filtri -->
    <livewire:gestionale-header-filter>
    <!-- fine import del componente gestionale header filter -->
  <hr/>
    <!-- import dei component livewire (tab: partite, pratiche, articoli) -->
    <livewire:table-pratiche />
    <hr/>
    <livewire:table-partite />
    <hr/>
    <livewire:table-articoli />
    <!-- fine dell'import dei component livewire (tab: partite, pratiche, articoli) -->
    <!-- import del component contenente i button per aprire i modal -->
    <livewire:gestionale-modal-component />
    

</div>
<!-- Inizio dei modal per gestire le azioni del gestionale -->
        <!-- modal per l'inserimento di un pagamento -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="PagamentoLongModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Aggungi un pagamento</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span>
                </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <!-- da aggiungere l'azione -->
                <div class="basic-form">
                    <form method="POST" action="#">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Ente</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Ente" value="" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Partita</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Partita" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Anno Rif.</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Anno Riferimento" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Anno</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Anno" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Numero</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Numero" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Carico</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Carico" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr/>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Tipologia</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Tipologia">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Imposta</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Imposta">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Decimali</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Decimali imposta" maxlenght="2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Mora</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Mora">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Decimali</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Decimali mora" maxlength="2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Data Pagamento</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Data Registrazione</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Note</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Email" minlength="3" maxlength="255"> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>      
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger light" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salva</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- modal per l'inserimento di un assegnatario -->
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title">Aggiungi un assegnatario</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <!-- da aggiungere l'azione -->
                    <form method="POST" action="#">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Seleziona assegnatari (tieni premuto shift per una selezione multipla):</label>
                                <select multiple class="form-control input-rounded" id="sel2">
                                  @if(!empty($users))
                                    @foreach($users as $u)
                                        <option value="{{$u->id}}">{{$u->username}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                  @endif
                                </select>
                              </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Data Assegnazione</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Data Assegn.">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger light" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salva</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- modal per visualizzare i pagamenti associati alla partita -->
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" id="ShowPagamentiModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title">Pagamenti associati alla partita</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <!-- da aggiungere il corpo del body -->
                    <p>Body da aggiungere, da capire i dati da mostrare a video</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger light" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i> Stampa</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- modal per visualizzare le procedure e le inesigibilita associati alla partita -->
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" id="ProcedureInesigibilitaModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title">Procedure e Inesigibilit&agrave;</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <!-- da aggiungere il corpo del body -->
                    <p>Body da aggiungere, da capire i dati da mostrare a video</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger light" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i> Stampa</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<!-- fine dei modal per gestire le azioni del gestionale -->
 <!--   IMPORTANTE: AGGIUNGERE IL CSRF TOKEN PRIMA DI ANDARE IN PRODUZIONE -->

@endsection
```

and the component gestionale-modal-component

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\MinutaPartita;

class GestionaleModalComponent extends Component
{
    protected $connection = null;
    public $articoli = null;
    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';
    protected $listeners = ['getPartite' => 'setId'];
    public $id_pratica = null;

    public function mount(Request $request)
    {
        if (null !== $request->get('throughMiddleware')) {
            $this->connection = 'tenant';
        } else {
            $this->connection = null;
        }
    }

    public function setId($id){
        $this->id_pratica = $id;
        dd($this->id_pratica);
    }

    //verifichiamo se è stata selezionata una pratica
    public function checkId(){
        //se null diamo un messaggio di errore, e non mostriamo il modal di inserimento
        if($this->id_pratica == null){
            return back()->with('error', 'Seleziona una pratica');
        }
    }

    public function setAssegnatario(){

    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.gestionale-modal-component');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The thing is you have

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PagamentoLongModal">Aggiungi pagamento</button>
```

this always is going to show the modal because it's a normal behavior through Bootstrap. You must do

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" wire:click="checkId">Aggiungi pagamento</button>
```

and in the component can

```
public function checkId()
{
    //se null diamo un messaggio di errore, e non mostriamo il modal di inserimento
    if($this->id_pratica == null){
         return back()->with('error', 'Seleziona una pratica');
    }
    else {
       $this->openModal();
    }
}
public function openModal()
{
   $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('openPagamentoLongModal');
}
public function closeModal()
{
   $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('closePagamentoLongModal');
}
```

in the blade, or the parent blade

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('openPagamentoLongModal', event => {
      $("#PagamentoLongModal").modal('show');
  })

  window.addEventListener('closePagamentoLongModal', event => {
      $("#PagamentoLongModal").modal('hide');
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Thank's so much...i've tried and it works well :-)

Comment: Is it possible to pass a variable via `GestionaleModalComponent.php` in a modal when it's open? example i need to pass $this->id_pratica when i open the modal `Aggiungi Assegnatario`

Comment: you need to find the way before open the modal bind all possible data to your blade and this can render it

Comment: Thanks..but i'm new with livewire and i've a question.
my structure is this, I have the view `gestionale.blade.php` in which I call the `gestionale-modal-component` component and to which I can pass data.
The modal code, however, is not in `gestionale-modal-component.blade.php` but in the `gestionale.blade.php`, and being new to livewire I don't know if it is possible to pass data to modal with this structure.
I thought maybe I can move the modal code inside the `gestionale-modal-component.blade.php` component, could that be a correct choice?

Comment: You have the modal Bootstrap code in the gestionale blade but inside this you call the component with Livewire directive <livewire:gestionale-modal-component> right? If you want share it here, close this post and open a new one with the new question. Greetings

Comment: Thanks you, you got it right, I'll open a new question

Answer (score 1):

here is also another option from [bootstrap v5 doctumentations](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#via-javascript).

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  
  var modalForm = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('modalForm'), {
        keyboard: false
    })

    window.addEventListener('closeModal', event => {
        modalForm.hide() 
    });

    window.addEventListener('openModal', event => {
        modalForm.show()  
    }); 

    </script>



// and use it inside your App\Http\Livewire class
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('openModal');
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('closeModal');
```